How to know if a front camera of a smartphone has a real flash?
I get the impression that some smartphone manufacturers are lying or misleading in claiming that certain phones have a front camera flash when they actually don't: They have only a "front screen flash" which is not really a flash at all in the traditional sense, and crucially doesn't make a significant different to the light levels in a even a small (5 m²) room.
Before purchasing it, how can I tell if the front camera of a smartphone has a real flash?

Can you give some specific examples of what you mean?

@PeterM https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkfN1fmHluE

Marketing would probably make a feature of such a capability (or at least listed in the features)

Originally I didn't use the term smartphone as is in the question and preferred the longer and more accurate term pocket computer ("smartphone") instead, but a mod changed it to smartphone and I will not argue with the mod on this matter.

"Smartphone" is a far more useful term for people searching for the question. That beats out pedantry every single time, particularly when the definition of "pocket computer" is ambiguous anyway (see e.g. Wikipedia).

@PhilipKendall I don't find a link for Wikipedia as a logical justification. However, me and other people who oppose labeling all non smartphone cellular devices as dumbphones will continue to use the term pocket computer (or better) but if a mod in SE changes it to smartphone, I personally won't change it back.

@hi_there A couple of things  1) Asking me to watch a 6+ minute long video isn't endearing - especially when it doesn't actually explain the fundamentals of your question.  2) Your question seems to be based on the idea that an LED can't be a "real" flash.  But you don't define what a "real" flash is.  3) Using the tern "pocket computer" instead of the almost universally used (and IMHO more accurate)  "smartphone" gives off teenage edgelord wanna be vibes.

@PeterM 1) I didn't post any link to any video so I suggest you to apologize for this false accusation. 2) I have done my best to define flash as a non photographer 3) As a non native speaker of English this slang of yours here is nonsense to me, I and other people will continue to say pocket computer over smartphone to not signal that all other phone devices are dumbphones; why not respect an opinion different than yours when no one forces you (or intend to force you) to share that opinion? I find it childish.

I think "pocket computer" is a strange and uncommon term to use - even confusing. If you don't like the term "smartphone", I suggest "camera phone" instead.

Ain't no "pocket computer" out there that has a real flash. Not a single one.

The unsatisfying short answer first:
To my knowledge NO current mobile phone uses a real strobe flash.
Why is that?
The problem with strobes and electronic shutter as employed in a mobile phone is, that the a "real" flash from a conventional flash bulb is really really really short.
This creates problems when you read out the sensor in a line-by-line fashion, as most sensors do. You have to make sure that you read all your sensor lines within the short timeframe of the flash of light. Otherwise you will get uneven lighting or even a half lit frame.
To overcome this, you can use techniques like high speed sync, where you simply prolong the flash by pulsing multiple flashes or by using a global shutter, where you read out all lines of the sensor at the same time.
A far easier solution is, to not use a flash bulb, but another source of concentrated light: a high yield LED. And that is the cheapest and most practical solution.
Regarding the power of the flash: As with all integrated flash lights, you have to make a compromise between some specifications:

Brighter is usually bigger. This means the light itself and the heat sinks to cool it.
Brighter usually means more power drain. So how much of you battery may the thing use?
Light is becoming weaker over distance by inverse square law. So adding more reach quickly becomes a real challenge, given the space constraints and energy available.

But why do you want to have a conventional flash?
I assume you associate a flash bulb with a light of higher intensity. And that is true for most conventional flashes. A flash emits a lot of light and heat during a very small time period.
Given the small light source and the placement near the lens, the real use of this as a means to create acceptable images is very limited.
As the camera in the phone is tailored to constant light, your best option, if you wanted to light bigger spaces, would be to invest into  constant lights like Photo LED lamps and light-formers to shape the light to your needs. The results will be looking way more professional than a built-in flash of any strength in your mobile phone ever could.

It is very common in technology that when some technical term gets reused misleadingly then the only reliable way of verifying the real property of the product becomes researching independent reviews or hands-on experience. There is quite a good number of reputable resources for smartphone reviews such as GSMArena or Notebook Check.
